# How to stack a decorator on top of defer.inlineCallback in Cyclone?

Tags: python, twisted, cyclone

I want to decorate post/get/... methods in my Cyclone request handlers with a simple decorator like this:

```
def json_errors(fun):
    def x(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            rv = fun(self, *args, **kwargs)
            return rv
        except cyclone.web.HTTPError, e:
            self.set_status(e.status_code)
            self.set_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
            self.write(e.log_message)
            self.finish()
    return x
```

However, because my post/get/... methods are already decorated with defer.inlineCallbacks I'm getting all kinds of deferred-related errors, no matter if I place my decorator before or after @defer.inlineCallbacks.

How can I add my decorator?

Comment: Can you show the errors?